# convert corpus into data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tm, corpus

I'm using the tm package to apply stemming, and I need to convert the resulting data into a data frame. 
A solution for this can be found here [R tm package vcorpus: Error in converting corpus to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703920/r-tm-package-vcorpus-corpus-to-dataframe), but in my case I have the content of the corpus as:

```
[[2195]]
i was very impress
```

instead of

```
[[2195]]
"i was very impress"
```

and because of this, if I apply

```
data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(mycorpus, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

the result will be

```
<NA>.
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Code below as an example:

```
sentence <- c("a small thread was loose on the sandals, otherwise it looked good")
mycorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(sentence))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, stemDocument, language = "english")

inspect(mycorpus)

[[1]]
a small thread was loo on the sandals, otherwi it look good

data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(mycorpus, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 text
1 <NA>
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe try `deparse` on the corpus list?

Comment: Thank you! no... I can't manage by using deparse...

Comment: Could you add some code with data to produce a minimal working example? From what I see so far, @RichardScriven 's idea sounds quite reasonable.

Comment: sure! by "can't manage" I meant that I wasn't able to apply the deparse function...

Comment: Oh, sorry.  just try it on one element first.  For example, `deparse(data[[2195]])`

Comment: No, I'm sorry! :) I doesn't work also.. I think that the problem must be a different one, because in the example I'm giving at the end the input is a string vector... so it should work... any ideas?

Comment: I've solved! I've applied a workaround... If I apply gsub to the corpus, the result has class = character. It works for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CristinaCerqueira - you should add that as an answer for future SO searchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By applying

```
gsub("http\\w+", "", mycorpus)
```

the output has class = character, so it works in my case.

Comment: I would be helpful if you would write the complete code for the conversion. Otherwise readers are left to the hit and trial method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce the problem using tm_0.6 in R 3.1.0 on a Mac:

```
> data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(mycorpus, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                                                                 text
content a small thread was loos on the sandals, otherwis it look good
```

If I had gotten those undesired results I would have immediately tried:

```
 data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(mycorpus, `[[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

... reasoning that since `'constent'` is a list-element name that `[['content']]` should have been able to so the serial extraction. It also looked to me that the unlist might not be needed with that approach:

```
> data.frame(text=sapply(mycorpus, `[[`, "content"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                                                           text
1 a small thread was loos on the sandals, otherwis it look good
```

Comment: Thanks! If I apply your suggestion it gives me the error "Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds"... But I've found a workaround for what I need.

Comment: I think you may have an outdated or broken installation of tm.