# Unable to view text using Inspect Function in R

Tags: r, corpus

I tried to view text data in Corpus using Inspect.

I am getting output as some numbers like:

```
[[19139]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 100
```

But when I've searched in Web Inspect command, most of snapshots are showing text as output.

***Question:***

In R, while trying to use Inspect function to view Corpus data, why am I not able to view text in it?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We have no idea how you've made your corpus or what exactly you are looking at.

Comment: Look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703920/r-tm-package-vcorpus-corpus-to-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the latest version of tm package, revert to old version. this problem wont appear. i too had the same problem. i changed from tm_0.6 to tm_0.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
strwrap(corpus[[19139]])
```