# Not able to convert webcorpus to dataframe

Tags: r

I was trying the codes suggested in the book *Text Mining with R* by *Julia Silge* given in page  of the book:

```
stock_tokens=stock_articles%>%
unnest(map(corpus,tidy))%>%
unnest_tokens(word,text)%>%
select(company,datetimestamp,word,id,heading)
```

**error message** from R:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: cannot coerce
>   class "c("WebCorpus", "VCorpus", "Corpus")" to a data.frame. In
>   addition: Warning message: In tidy.default(.x[[i]], ...) :   No method
>   for tidying an S3 object of class WebCorpus , using as.data.frameNo
>   method for tidying an S3 object of class VCorpus , using
>   as.data.frameNo method for tidying an S3 object of class Corpus ,
>   using as.data.frame

I am not able to find the solution from the net. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what a WebCorpus is but this older question about Corpus to data.frame may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703920/r-tm-package-vcorpus-error-in-converting-corpus-to-data-frame

Comment: I tried that too. But it is not working. I am getting the same error message